# How to handle fields like user_id ,login token etc. , that are common to entire applicaton

Tags: android, class, architecture

Is there a better architecture that we can follow other that making these fields static(bad for performance) or storing in Shared Preference.

Comment: Why a downvote on question , Is it not clear?

Answer (score 0):

Either use Shared prefs or a database. Both are optimized for quick and (more or less) safe access. It might be worth your while to read about Architecture Components, Room (or others such as ObjectBox, Realm, etc) and repository pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Android Jetpack would be your best option. Check out the documentation on Data Binding, it would allow you to access fields like user_id without writing tons of boilerplate java/kotlin code, by injecting the data directly into you xml code. Here's the link: [Android Jetpack Data Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in saving two/three Strings as static variables, In fact it is the fastest way to get repeatedly used variables. I prefer Application class to do so(static variables of Application class), but the issue is if your app happens to crash for some reason, application class is recreated and app starts from the previous activity, alas your static variables are long gone, be aware of this pitfall

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how/when you are using these static elements.
A few application global variables like userSession object might make sense to store in the MyApplication file itself and made exposed throughout the app so you confirm it is valid when app returns from background each time for example.

SharedPreference is not a great place to store secure elements as it is on file storage in unencrypted xml format which rooted phones and others may have access to get to.

Database is a fine option, but it requires more code bloat and requires a database connection and query everytime you want to use the token if you don't plan to store it in RAM.

Another option is a singleton class that is meant to store your necessary application elements like FirebaseHelper for example that could populate into RAM on app startup and utilize your variables throughout the application life.

So really depends on your app needs. You can also use a SecureSharedPreference tool. There are a few open source options out there for this that you can just include in your project that encrypt the xml elements for you if you prefer to use the xml for storing these items.

If it was me, I would either you a secureSharedPref if it was simple things like userId, Token, or things like that that are fairly harmless. Of course it will encrypt them, but worst case if they got your token, they could make a few API calls if they knew what they were doing, unlikely. Now storing things like password, bank info, medical records, or anything else sensitive definitely should be in a Database. In fact, I would go one step further and layer it with SQLCipher.

So long story short is it depends on what you are storing and the risk assessment of it's content being accessed and each app will be different.

Absolutely nothing wrong with storing some static variables or singletons. Anyone building an enterprise level application will have a fair amount of statics in their application if it is architected in a good way.